# Weird Trainer Naming Issue in Gym

Tags: pokemon-go

Today I looked at mons in a gym and noticed one was named with the letter "t" followed by 13 numbers that seemed random.  When I entered battle, the name changed to letters, and the new name was derogatory towards another player.  How are people doing this?
EDIT: Changed redaction to only the other player's name.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely that this player's name was detected as offensive and was removed and the `t+digits` is a temporary or permanent replacement name.  The gym may use a different database table to store the relevant information and may have kept the player's old name before it was banned.

Comment: That has to be the reason.  I noticed that I put a Pokémon in a gym, renamed it, and when I went to the gym at a later time, it still had the original name I gave it, not the new rename, which surprised me more than it still being in the gym.  I didn't attempt training against it to see if the name changed to the new name.  Might try that sometime.

Answer (score 1):

I think his username was too long so that you couldn't see the offensive part until you entered the battle...

For example, he could put h4848486468446864yourdadisreallybad, but you'd only see the end of it.

Comment: I don't think that's it, since the max length of a trainer name is 15 characters.  I changed the image so the redacted part is not so long.

Comment: Oh, then i really dont know sorry :(